# Передача id сущности vs Bundle: плюсы и минусы?

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть список сущностей, например `Event`. По клику на сущность переходим на детальный экран. Можно ли передавать сущность в `Bundle` или лучше передавать только Id. Какие плюсы и минусы у этих подходов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильнее передавать параметром только `Id`, а сами элементы будут получаться из репозитория по этому айди. Если у вас есть что положить в `Bundle`, значит вы можете закешировать это через репозиторий.
В таком случае вы всегда можете получить актуальную информацию из репозитория, а не потенциально устаревшую из параметров.

К тому же, если вам нужно передать объект с большим количество полей, или со списками данных, в определённый момент у вас может произойти `TransactionTooLargeException`, если вы будете использовать `Bundle`.